# JavaScript Algorithm not filtering correctly

Tags: javascript

Pretty new to JavaScript. I am writing a program that shows quotes at random. The issue is that I also want the same quote to never be repeated unless the entire array of quotes have been used.

The program does generate the quotes but they are not unique each time. Here is the script:

```
    // Random Quote Generator - Justin Duncan

// Create the array of quote objects and name it quotes
var quotes = [{
    quote: "I love you the more in that I believe you had" +
      " liked me for my own sake and for nothing else.",
    source: "John Keats",
    categorization: "love",
    year: ""
  },
  {
    quote: "But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.",
    source: "Ernest Hemingway",
    categorization: "philosophy",
    year: ""
  },
  {
    quote: "When you reach the end of your rope, tie a knot in it and hang on.",
    source: "Franklin D. Roosevelt",
    categorization: "motivation",
    year: ""
  },
  {
    quote: "There is nothing permanent except change.",
    source: "Heraclitus",
    categorization: "philosophy",
    year: ""

  },
  {
    quote: "You cannot shake hands with a clenched fist",
    source: "Indira Gandhi",
    categorization: "philosophy",
    year: "1971"
  },
  {
    quote: "Learning never exhausts the mind",
    source: " Leonardo da Vinci",
    categorization: "philosophy",
    year: ""
  },
  {
    quote: "There is no charm equal to tenderness of heart.",
    source: "Jane Austen",
    categorization: "motivation",
    year: ""
  },
];


//To track quotes that have been shown and remove them from random pool
var shownQuotes = [];
// grabs copy of quotes to manipulate
var notShownQuotes = Object.create(quotes);

// Create the getRandomQuote function and name it getRandomQuote
function getRandomQuote() {
  if (shownQuotes.length !== 0) {
    //checks if a shown quote is in the notShownQuotes arry and removes it
    shownQuotes.forEach(function(shownQuote) {
      for (var i = 0; i < notShownQuotes.length; i++) {
        if (shownQuote.quote == notShownQuotes[i].quote) {
          notShownQuotes.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    })
  }
  //resets the array if all have been shown
  if (notShownQuotes.length === 0) {
    notShownQuotes = Object.create(quotes);
  }
  // generates random number according to array length
  var returnVal = Math.round(Math.random() * notShownQuotes.length - 1);
  // in case returnval is an invalid number because of small array size
  if (returnVal <= 0) {
    return notShownQuotes[0];
  } else {
    return notShownQuotes[returnVal]
  }
}

// Create the printQuote funtion and name it printQuote
function printQuote() {
  var tempQuote = getRandomQuote();
  var str = '<p class="quote">' +
    ` ${tempQuote.quote}.</p>` +
    `<p class="source">${tempQuote.source}`;
  if (tempQuote.year.length !== 0) {
    str +=
      `<span class="year">${tempQuote.year}</span></p>`
  } else {
    str += '</p>'
  }
  //this portion prints to the document
  document.getElementById('quote-box').innerHTML = str;
  //change background color
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = ran3Color();
  //change button as well :)
  document.getElementById('loadQuote').style.backgroundColor = ran3Color();
  //clears timer
  clearInterval(timer);
  // resets timer
  timer = setInterval(printQuote, 5000);
}
//random color generator
function ran3Color() {
  var r = Math.round(Math.random() * 360);
  var g = Math.round(Math.random() * 360);
  var b = Math.round(Math.random() * 360);
  return `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
}

//set interval for timer
var timer = setInterval(printQuote, 50);

// This event listener will respond to "Show another quote" button clicks
// when user clicks anywhere on the button, the "printQuote" function is called
document.getElementById('loadQuote').addEventListener("click", printQuote, false);
```

I hope it is something small. This is not homework, I am wanting to ensure I understand how to manipulate Js and I obviously am doing something wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Added the entire app.js in case that helps understand what I have done and the direction I am looking at.

Comment: The assignment `notShownQuotes = quotes;` does not make a copy of the `quotes` array. It just copies a *reference* to the array, so both variables end up pointing to the same single array.

Comment: @Pointy I think this is the source of my issue as well. I am thinking to research a better way to pass around variables since these are not copies but references. Did I provide enough code? Should I give the whole app.js file?

Comment: I think Saeed's answer is pretty close. For the record I'd do this an entirely different way: make an array of numbers from 0 up to `quotes.length - 1`; shuffle the array; then just iterate through that array to get the quote indexes. They'll be random, and there'll never be a repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code have 2 problems

**1-** When you remove one item of array, decrease counter

```
notShownQuotes.splice(i, 1);
i --;
```

**2-** Update your `notShownQuotes` array everytime you show an item

```
if (returnVal <= 0) {
    notShownQuotes.splice(0, 1);
    return notShownQuotes[0];
} else {
    notShownQuotes.splice(returnVal, 1);
    return notShownQuotes[returnVal];
}
```

Full code will be

```js
// Random Quote Generator - Justin Duncan

// Create the array of quote objects and name it quotes
var quotes = [{
  quote: "I love you the more in that I believe you had" + " liked me for my own sake and for nothing else.",
  source: "John Keats",
  categorization: "love",
  year: ""
}, {
  quote: "But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.",
  source: "Ernest Hemingway",
  categorization: "philosophy",
  year: ""
}, {
  quote: "When you reach the end of your rope, tie a knot in it and hang on.",
  source: "Franklin D. Roosevelt",
  categorization: "motivation",
  year: ""
}, {
  quote: "There is nothing permanent except change.",
  source: "Heraclitus",
  categorization: "philosophy",
  year: ""
}, {
  quote: "You cannot shake hands with a clenched fist",
  source: "Indira Gandhi",
  categorization: "philosophy",
  year: "1971"
}, {
  quote: "Learning never exhausts the mind",
  source: " Leonardo da Vinci",
  categorization: "philosophy",
  year: ""
}, {
  quote: "There is no charm equal to tenderness of heart.",
  source: "Jane Austen",
  categorization: "motivation",
  year: ""
}, ];

//To track quotes that have been shown and remove them from random pool
var shownQuotes = [];
// grabs copy of quotes to manipulate
var notShownQuotes = Object.create(quotes);

// Create the getRandomQuote function and name it getRandomQuote
function getRandomQuote() {
  if (shownQuotes.length !== 0) {
    console.log(shownQuotes)
    console.log(notShownQuotes)
    //checks if a shown quote is in the notShownQuotes arry and removes it
    shownQuotes.forEach(function(shownQuote) {
      for (var i = 0; i < notShownQuotes.length; i++) {
        if (shownQuote.quote == notShownQuotes[i].quote) {
          notShownQuotes.splice(i, 1);
          i--;
        }
      }
    });
  }
  //resets the array if all have been shown
  if (notShownQuotes.length === 0) {
    notShownQuotes = Object.create(quotes);
  }
  // generates random number according to array length
  var returnVal = Math.round(Math.random() * notShownQuotes.length - 1);
  // in case returnval is an invalid number because of small array size
  if (returnVal <= 0) {
    notShownQuotes.splice(0, 1);
    return notShownQuotes[0];
  } else {
    notShownQuotes.splice(returnVal, 1);
    return notShownQuotes[returnVal];
  }
}

// Create the printQuote funtion and name it printQuote
function printQuote() {
  var tempQuote = getRandomQuote();
  var str =
    '<p class="quote">' +
    ` ${tempQuote.quote}.</p>` +
    `<p class="source">${tempQuote.source}`;
  if (tempQuote.year.length !== 0) {
    str += `<span class="year">${tempQuote.year}</span></p>`;
  } else {
    str += "</p>";
  }
  //this portion prints to the document
  document.getElementById("quote-box").innerHTML = str;
  //change background color
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = ran3Color();
  //change button as well :)
  document.getElementById("loadQuote").style.backgroundColor = ran3Color();
  //clears timer
  clearInterval(timer);
  // resets timer
  timer = setInterval(printQuote, 5000);
}
//random color generator
function ran3Color() {
  var r = Math.round(Math.random() * 360);
  var g = Math.round(Math.random() * 360);
  var b = Math.round(Math.random() * 360);
  return `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
}

//set interval for timer
var timer = setInterval(printQuote, 50);

// This event listener will respond to "Show another quote" button clicks
// when user clicks anywhere on the button, the "printQuote" function is called
document
  .getElementById("loadQuote")
  .addEventListener("click", printQuote, false);
```

```html
<button id="loadQuote">click</button>

<p id="quote-box"></p>
```

Another solution is: Store just showed quotes and after all, empty array again

```js
// Random Quote Generator - Justin Duncan

// Create the array of quote objects and name it quotes
var quotes = [{
  quote: "I love you the more in that I believe you had" + " liked me for my own sake and for nothing else.",
  source: "John Keats",
  categorization: "love",
  year: ""
}, {
  quote: "But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.",
  source: "Ernest Hemingway",
  categorization: "philosophy",
  year: ""
}, {
  quote: "When you reach the end of your rope, tie a knot in it and hang on.",
  source: "Franklin D. Roosevelt",
  categorization: "motivation",
  year: ""
}, {
  quote: "There is nothing permanent except change.",
  source: "Heraclitus",
  categorization: "philosophy",
  year: ""
}, {
  quote: "You cannot shake hands with a clenched fist",
  source: "Indira Gandhi",
  categorization: "philosophy",
  year: "1971"
}, {
  quote: "Learning never exhausts the mind",
  source: " Leonardo da Vinci",
  categorization: "philosophy",
  year: ""
}, {
  quote: "There is no charm equal to tenderness of heart.",
  source: "Jane Austen",
  categorization: "motivation",
  year: ""
}, ];

//To track quotes that have been shown and remove them from random pool
var shownQuotes = [];

// Create the getRandomQuote function and name it getRandomQuote
function getRandomQuote() {

  if (shownQuotes.length == quotes.length) {
    shownQuotes = [];
  }

  // generates random number according to array length
  var returnVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length - 1) + 1;
  // in case returnval is an invalid number because of small array size

  while (shownQuotes.indexOf(returnVal) != -1) {
    returnVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length - 1) + 1;
  }

  if (returnVal <= 0) {
    shownQuotes.push(0)
    return quotes[0];
  } else {
    shownQuotes.push(returnVal)
    return quotes[returnVal];
  }
}

// Create the printQuote funtion and name it printQuote
function printQuote() {
  var tempQuote = getRandomQuote();
  var str =
    '<p class="quote">' +
    ` ${tempQuote.quote}.</p>` +
    `<p class="source">${tempQuote.source}`;
  if (tempQuote.year.length !== 0) {
    str += `<span class="year">${tempQuote.year}</span></p>`;
  } else {
    str += "</p>";
  }
  //this portion prints to the document
  document.getElementById("quote-box").innerHTML = str;
  //change background color
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = ran3Color();
  //change button as well :)
  document.getElementById("loadQuote").style.backgroundColor = ran3Color();
  //clears timer
  clearInterval(timer);
  // resets timer
  timer = setInterval(printQuote, 5000);
}
//random color generator
function ran3Color() {
  var r = Math.round(Math.random() * 360);
  var g = Math.round(Math.random() * 360);
  var b = Math.round(Math.random() * 360);
  return `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
}

//set interval for timer
var timer = setInterval(printQuote, 50);

// This event listener will respond to "Show another quote" button clicks
// when user clicks anywhere on the button, the "printQuote" function is called
document
  .getElementById("loadQuote")
  .addEventListener("click", printQuote, false);
```

```html
<button id="loadQuote">click</button>

<p id="quote-box"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the part with `forEach` and then `splice` to create a new array is a bit confusing. You could use a simple `Array.filter` to get rid of already used quotes, for example:

```
let shownQuotes = [];

function getRandomQuote () {
    // if all quotes were used reset shownQuotes so all quotes can be shown again
    if (shownQuotes.length === quotes.length) {
        shownQuotes = [];
    }
    // filter all quotes that have been used
    const unusedQuotes = quotes.filter(quote => !shownQuotes.includes(quote));
    // get a random index between [0, unusedQuotes.length)
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * unusedQuotes.length);
    const randomQuote = unusedQuotes[randomIndex];

    // add the element to the quotes already shown.
    shownQuotes.push(randomQuote);

    return randomQuote;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to replace your code but i don't have inputs.
I use simple inputs.

so i removed ".quote"s from

```
if (shownQuote.quote === notShownQuotes[i].quote) {
```

and then you have one mistake:

**I think you try to splice array to remove duplicate objects. be careful when use "splice" in "for" you must don't use "i++" and must use "i--" !**
If you use "i++" maybe after splice skipped one object and don't compare! see whats happen to "3" in my example inputs.

please run below scripts. compare outputs and **see last code (Changed code) maybe help you.**

comment: first code doesn't work and reset because inputs don't have "quote"s

in upper if checked (undefined === undefined)

Your code:

```js
console.log('Your code:')

var notShownQuotes = [1,2,3,3,4,5,4,6], shownQuotes = [1,2,3,6], quotes = [1,2,3,4,6];
function getRandomQuote() {
  if (shownQuotes.length !== 0) {
    //checks if a shown quote is in the notShownQuotes arry and removes it
    shownQuotes.forEach(function(shownQuote) {
      for (var i = 0; i < notShownQuotes.length; i++) {
        if (shownQuote.quote === notShownQuotes[i].quote) {
   notShownQuotes.splice(i, 1);
   console.log('remove ' + shownQuote);
        }
      }
    })
  }
  //resets the array if all have been shown
  if (notShownQuotes.length === 0) {
    notShownQuotes = quotes;
 console.log('reseted');
  }
  // generates random number according to array length
  var returnVal = Math.round(Math.random() * notShownQuotes.length - 1);
  // in case returnval is an invalid number because of small array size
  if (returnVal <= 0) {
    return notShownQuotes[0];
  } else {
    return notShownQuotes[returnVal]
  }
}
console.log('getRandomQuote: ' + getRandomQuote());
```

Your code Without ".quote"s:

```js
console.log('Your code Without ".quote"s:')

var notShownQuotes = [1,2,3,3,4,5,4,6], shownQuotes = [1,2,3,6], quotes = [1,2,3,4,6];
function getRandomQuote2() {
  if (shownQuotes.length !== 0) {
    //checks if a shown quote is in the notShownQuotes arry and removes it
    shownQuotes.forEach(function(shownQuote) {
      for (var i = 0; i < notShownQuotes.length; i++) {
        if (shownQuote === notShownQuotes[i]) {
   notShownQuotes.splice(i, 1);
   console.log('remove ' + shownQuote);
        }
      }
    })
  }
  //resets the array if all have been shown
  if (notShownQuotes.length === 0) {
    notShownQuotes = quotes;
 console.log('reseted');
  }
  // generates random number according to array length
  var returnVal = Math.round(Math.random() * notShownQuotes.length - 1);
  // in case returnval is an invalid number because of small array size
  if (returnVal <= 0) {
    return notShownQuotes[0];
  } else {
    return notShownQuotes[returnVal]
  }
}
console.log('getRandomQuote: ' + getRandomQuote2());
```

**Changed code: #####################**

```js
console.log('Changed code: #####################')

var notShownQuotes = [1,2,3,3,4,5,4,6], shownQuotes = [1,2,3,6], quotes = [1,2,3,4,6];
function getRandomQuote3() {
  if (shownQuotes.length !== 0) {
    //checks if a shown quote is in the notShownQuotes arry and removes it
    shownQuotes.forEach(function(shownQuote) {
      for (var i = notShownQuotes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (shownQuote === notShownQuotes[i]) {
   notShownQuotes.splice(i, 1);
   console.log('remove ' + shownQuote);
        }
      }
    })
  }
  //resets the array if all have been shown
  if (notShownQuotes.length === 0) {
    notShownQuotes = quotes;
 console.log('reseted');
  }
  // generates random number according to array length
  var returnVal = Math.round(Math.random() * notShownQuotes.length - 1);
  // in case returnval is an invalid number because of small array size
  if (returnVal <= 0) {
    return notShownQuotes[0];
  } else {
    return notShownQuotes[returnVal]
  }
}
console.log('getRandomQuote: ' + getRandomQuote3());
```

in end. sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score -1):

TRY

```
  var temp_qoute="";
        function getRandomQuote() {
          if (shownQuotes.length !== 0) {
            //checks if a shown quote is in the notShownQuotes arry and removes it
            shownQuotes.forEach(function(shownQuote) {
              for (var i = 0; i < notShownQuotes.length; i++) {
                if (shownQuote.quote === notShownQuotes[i].quote && notShownQuotes[i].quote!=temp_qoute) {
                temp_qoute= notShownQuotes[i].quote
                notShownQuotes.splice(i, 1);
                }
              }
            })
          }
          //resets the array if all have been shown
          if (notShownQuotes.length === 0) {
            notShownQuotes = quotes;
          }
          // generates random number according to array length
          var returnVal = Math.round(Math.random() * notShownQuotes.length - 1);
          // in case returnval is an invalid number because of small array size
          if (returnVal <= 0) {
            return notShownQuotes[0];
          } else {
            return notShownQuotes[returnVal]
          }
        }
```

Comment: Code-only answers without any explanation of what the original problem was, how you changed it, and why your changes fix the problem are not helpful. And looking at your answer I don't think it will actually work.

Comment: i just add variable temp to  store any result will match with search to keep this value in next loop ..consider ` && notShownQuotes[i].quote!=temp_qoute`

Comment: There are other bugs in the code. Have you tested your changes?

Comment: No.can you give me the elements (tags) to make  executable  code and create useful function for you ?

Comment: @khalidJ-A I added the entire app.js file for you. I think this has to do with me taking a reference to objects instead of copies. While researching I am seeing that copying objects are not straightforward in javaScript. Something to do with shallow copies and hard copies.